# D3.js Histogramm, colums' width according to date range

Tags: javascript, date, d3.js, range, histogram

I am trying to fix the width of the columns of a histogram.

Either I get a column at "d.date.start" or "d.date.end", obviously. Both just give me columns but neiter produce columns of the whole date range.

Do I have to convert both parsed "start" and "end" time to unix and substract start from end? and how do I have to code ".value()"?

I went through Github, ObservablesHQ and Stackoverflow, VizHub and Youtube.
Anybody can help me?

My both approaches:

```
const parser = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
const bins = d3
      .bin()
      .value((d) => parser(d.date.start))
      .domain(x.domain())
      .thresholds(x.ticks(20))(events);
```

Or:

```
const parser = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
const bins = d3
      .bin()
      .value((d) => parser(d.date.end))
      .domain(x.domain())
      .thresholds(x.ticks(20))(events);
```

I expect the columns to be of a relative width to the date ranges.